# Nodejs-Typescript; I need to avoid instantiating from function

Tags: node.js, typescript, function, arrow-functions

is there any other way to invoke the "hello" service without having to instantiate the userServices from the "health" method?? thanks!

```
export default class HealthController {
  app;
  asd = new userServices();
  constructor() {
    this.app = new userServices();
  }

  async health(req: Request, res: Response) {
    try {
      console.log( await new userServices().hello());  <-----
      res.send({ status: "Service Alive" });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      res.status(500).send({ status: "error health" });
    }
  }
  
}
```

avoiding using the arrow function because I'm going to implement a decorator later

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your code is creating a `userServices` instance three times. but I think you want to have a single property `app` that holds the instance so the rest of your class can just use that property.

If I understand you right, then you just need to access the `this.app` property inside your `health()` method.

```
export default class HealthController {
  app: userServices; // declare the property and it's type.

  constructor() {
    this.app = new userServices(); // assign the property in the constructor
  }

  async health(req: Request, res: Response) {
    console.log(await this.app.hello()); // use property from the `this` object
  } 
}
```

[Working example on Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=true&ts=4.7.2#code/MYGwhgzhAECuEFMBOBlZA3AlsBMDeAsAFDSnSQCeAdsNABYIggD2AFAJTSElm9IIAXWEirQA5AybMxxXgF9iCosVCQYACQRgQAugGFmVAUmZNkXWeQAOVgFxxEqDNlwBuaAHoP0ACYJV-NC6CNBWJlbIAhTkVD7QmAJiMFERAHTElsCGEMawwALMSBwWPKS6mBCpYDbQALzQVAgA7g7IaEhYOBAc7l7kUJgA5qLBoeGR0ZgjDNBZVDlIeQVIlkqWlDT0Wjp0xdy8cxCmCKksg6xgTWAJQXQVVTapkiwc7L3e8CFhzBFIUdAAMxMAFtbiEAAblCDg6DMABGACt-AJVtBFBkiI0WpptLoDEYTGYiuwnttdBwgA)

Comment: I appreciate the help and your time.

Unfortunately it doesn't work for me :(
the error is as follows: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'app')

Comment: If you click the click at the bottom of my answer and then you click "run" in the top left, you should see the log output of `"hello"` on the right. So this code works. How does your answer differ from my answer?

Comment: you're right, it works in the example, I have it the same way but it doesn't work for me... with array function it works, but I need it to work with the method :(, I'll be checking to see what happens... thank you very much for all!

Comment: hey I managed to make it work, I'll tell you what I had to modify...

from routes ->
I had to add the "bind" function

example:

`export default class HealthRoutes {
   private router = express.Router();
   public getRouter() {
     return this.router;
   }
   builder() {
     const healthController = new HealthController();
     ->>> this.router.get("/", healthController.health.bind(healthController));
   }
}`

why would this happen?